# Pug add scripts from includes before the closing body tag

Tags: node.js, pug

I have some pug templates, which use the `include` functionality.

For example I have a `index.pug` and a `detail.pug`, which act as the parent layouts.

```
body
  | I am the index.pug
  include my_partial
  | Some text
```

```
body
  | I am the detail.pug
  include my_partial
  | Some text
```

The `my_partial` looks like this:

```
| Inside partial
script(src="mypartial.js")
```

The `my_partial` is consequently loaded by several pages.

Now if I render it like this, then the `script` tag will be loaded in-between the html code:

```
body
  | I am the index.pug

  | Inside partial
  script(src="mypartial.js")
  
  | Some text
```

I want that the `script` tag of the partial is located before the closing body tag of the parent template.

**What I have tried:**

I tried to use the `block append scripts` method:

```
body
  | I am the index.pug
  include my_partial
  block scripts
```

And the `my_partial`:

```
| Inside partial
block appends scripts
  script(src="mypartial.js)
```

The problem is that I can not use `extend`, because my partial has multiple parents. And without `extend` nothing happens.

How can I append scripts to a block if the included partial has multiple parents?

**UPDATE**

What works for me, but looks like a bad workaround:

```
 | I am the index.pug
 - var bodyScripts = []

 include my_partial

 each scriptPath in bodyScripts
   script(src=scriptPath)
```

```
| Inside partial
- bodyScripts.push('mypartial.js')
```

Thank you for any idea!

Comment: I think you're confusing an `include` with template inheritance (which uses `block` declarations and the `extends` keyword). They're two separate concepts. Blocks don't work with includes. Can you share more information about what your partial and its scripts are for? That will help determine if you should be using inheritance or includes or both. It might be that you just need to break it up into two separate partials, one for the markup and one for the scripts.

Comment: Thank you Sean, I basically want to use some of my partials as web components. The partial has the html and a reference to my web-component script (E.g. a modal). If a parent template includes the modal_partial.pug it should automatically append the script from the modal_partial to the end of the parent. Right now I inlcude the modal_partial and then "manually" add the modal-js-script to the end. (Obviously I only include those web-components only once per page)

Comment: Is the web component markup essentially a `<template>` element?

Comment: Right now it is just a custom tag ``<myCustomTag>My custom element</...>``. If there is a way with ``<templates>`` I would be open for it

Comment: That seems like a better case for a [mixin](https://pugjs.org/language/mixins.html).

Comment: Are the various js files for the custom components large enough that you only want to load them if they're present on the page? I think the common practice would be to just bundle and minify all of the js into a single js file and load that once. It would get cached for subsequent page visits, and reduces the number of requests.